# Some questions on Tychonoff's theorem from Munkres book

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the proof of Tychonoff's theorem from Munkres book and some moments of the below picture I cannot understand. So let me ask you my question please:

**Question 1:**  Why $\mathcal{A}$ has the finite intersection property? So if I take any finite collection of such ellipses and their intersection will contain $p$ and $q$, right?

**Question 2:** It is not so obvious to me why the point $(1/2,1/2)$ does not belong to all elements of $\mathcal{A}$? Can anyone explain it more clearer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Your set does not consist of the *ellipses*, it consists of the **elliptical regions** bounded by those ellipses. That's the same as the difference between the disk and the circle (the disk is the circle plus everything inside the circle).

Yes, the family has the finite intersection property because any finite such collection will have intersection that includes both $p$ and $q$.

However, given any point $y$ that is not on the line between $p$ and $q$, you can figure out the sum of the distances $d(y,p)$ and $d(y,q)$. Say it $d(y,p)+d(y,q) = N$. Let $L$ be the distance between $p$ and $q$.

Now pick any number $M$ with $L\lt M \lt N$. You can certainly form a triangle with base the line $pq$, and whose two other sides have lengths that add to $M$.

Now, consider the elliptical region determined by the ellipse with focii at $p$ and $q$, and defined by
$$ d(x,p) + d(x,q) = M.$$
So, all points $x$ with $d(x,p)+d(x,q) \leq M$.

This is a member of your family. However, the original point $y$ is not in this region, so it is not in the intersection of the family.

You can do this for any point not on that line. In particular, for the example at hand, you can do it for $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: A triangle has three sides, and the sum of the lengths of two of them should always be more than the length of the the third side. Pick a poiint, $y$, and draw the line from $y$ to $p$, from $p$ to $q$, and from $q$ to $y$. The sum of the first and third distance should be $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Arturo! This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any finite intersection will contain the points $p$ and $q$ so the FIP is quite obvious, indeed.

And if we have a much thinner ellipse, $(\frac12,\frac12)$ will not lie in it. Just make it a little thinner than the thinnest one that is drawn.